# SharePoint Search - KQL query (results limitation)

Tags: search, kql-query

I have a issue with limiting search results using PnP Modern Search.

In addition to pulling all *.docx documents from the document library, I would like to skip those that have the name "Attachments" in the path.

Example:

1. https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents/Test1/Attachments
2. https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents/Test2/Attachments
3. https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents/Test3/Attachments
4. https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents/Test4/Attachments

I would like to find documents under Test* folders but not under Attachments.
So far I have tried the following KQL query but does not work:

```
 {searchTerms} path:https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents -path:https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents/*/Attachments/* fileextension:docx
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The **Path** managed property is configured as **Complete Matching**.

Create **new managed property** without **Complete Matching** and recrawl Documents list/library [See answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70743/2013-results-source-query-path-shows-zero-relevantresults)

When you are creating new managed property "NewPath" look at default managed property "Path" and map all crawled properties like in "Path" managed property. [see steps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/create-managed-search-property-in-sharepoint-online/)

Your new query:

```
 {searchTerms} path:https://sp.online/sites/DEV/Documents -NewPath:/Attachments fileextension:docx
```

NewPath = new managed property same like Path but only without Complete Matching